# Store time between records

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table called asset_usages which records the viewing of an asset by a viewer.  The relevant fields are

```
id (int)
asset_id (int)
viewer_type (string)
viewer_id (int)
viewed_at (datetime)
```

I have a new field i just added called time_between_viewings, which is an int field representing seconds. I want to set this to the time, in seconds, since that asset was last viewed.  So, if i had these four records:

```
+-----+----------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| id  | asset_id | viewer_id | viewer_type | viewed_at           | time_between_viewings |
+-----+----------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| 506 |     7342 |      1182 | User        | 2009-01-05 11:10:01 |      NULL             |
| 509 |     7342 |      1182 | User        | 2009-01-05 11:12:47 |      NULL             |
| 514 |     6185 |      1182 | User        | 2009-01-05 11:14:28 |      NULL             |
| 524 |     6185 |      1182 | User        | 2009-01-05 11:28:18 |      NULL             |
| 618 |     1234 |      1182 | User        | 2009-01-05 11:29:03 |      NULL             |
| 729 |     1234 |      1182 | User        | 2009-01-05 11:29:01 |      NULL             |        
+-----+----------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

then time_between_viewings should be set as follows:

```
+-----+----------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| id  | asset_id | viewer_id | viewer_type | viewed_at           | time_between_viewings |
+-----+----------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| 506 |     7342 |      1182 | User        | 2009-01-05 11:10:01 |      NULL             |
| 509 |     7342 |      1182 | User        | 2009-01-05 11:12:47 |      166              |
| 514 |     6185 |      1182 | User        | 2009-01-05 11:14:28 |      NULL             |
| 524 |     6185 |      1182 | User        | 2009-01-05 11:28:18 |      830              |
| 618 |     1234 |      1182 | User        | 2009-01-05 11:29:03 |      2                |
| 729 |     1234 |      1182 | User        | 2009-01-05 11:29:01 |      NULL             |     
+-----+----------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

where 166 and 830 are the time difference between each pair, in seconds.

What would be the sql to populate this field?  I can't quite figure it out.

IMPORTANT NOTE:  the data is not always inserted into the db in chronological order.  Ie, you could have two records A and B, where B has a higher id but A has a later value for viewed_at.  So, looking for the first matching record with a lower id would not necesarily give you the previous viewing by the same person - you'll need to examine all the records in the database.

thanks! max

EDIT - stated that time_between_viewings is an int field representing seconds.

EDIT - added a couple of rows as an example of a row with a higher id but earlier timestamp

EDIT - i just realised that i didn't stipulate the question properly.  The time_between_viewings should be equal to the time since the asset was last viewed by *the same viewer*, ie the time between the record and the previous (based on viewed_at) record that has the same asset_id, viewer_id and viewer_type.  The example data i gave still holds, but i could have put in some different viewer_id and viewer_type values to flesh the example out a bit.

Comment: Please, if you can, add the unit to `time_between_viewings`, for future maintainers.  You should at least be able to add a comment to it, if you can't change the name of the column itself.

Comment: *"the data is not always inserted into the db in chronological order"* Add a few rows that illustrate this to your sample data.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - added a note about time_between_viewings

Comment: @Mike Sherrill 'Catcall' - done

Comment: Dont do this. The `time_between_viewings` field is not fully dependent on the PK, its value is also related to the "previous" record. It is also redundant.

Comment: @wildplasser it is an efficiency measure.  I have around 800,000 records in this table, and need to get counts of resource views, ignoring repeated viewings within a variable time period.  Calculating this every time is slow.  Having a field which effectively caches the time since last viewing should give a big speedup.

Comment: {viewer_id, asset_id,vieuwed_at} appear to be a candidate key, an ordered scan + window + lag() would give you exactly what you want.

Comment: @wildplasser - can you elucidate on this in an answer please?  I'm not sure what you mean.  thanks! max

Comment: Well the problem is that _given WINDOW functions_ , this kind of query is easy (about five lines). But mysql does not have window functions. And the second candidate would be to update the table from itself (about ten lines). But mysql does not allow the "destination table" to be referenced at the the RHS (without an aggregate IIRC) (BTW: that is Catcall's solution: approx ten lines) So you are stuck to maintaining computed values by means of bulky code (approx twenty lines).

Answer (score 0):

If would be helpful if you prepared sample table and data inserts.
Read this link to learn why it is so important if you want to get help : http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html
This time I created it for you, click on this link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9719a/2

And try this query (you will find this query together with sample data under the above link) :

```
select alias1.*,
       timestampdiff( second, previous_viewed_at, viewed_at ) 
         as time_between_viewings
from (
select alias.*,
       (
         select viewed_at from (
             select
             ( select count(*) from asset_usages y
                where x.asset_id = y.asset_id 
                and y.viewed_at < x.viewed_at
              ) as rn,
              x.* 
              from asset_usages x
          ) xyz
          where xyz.asset_id = alias.asset_id 
               and xyz.rn = alias.rn - 1
       ) previous_viewed_at
from (
  select
    ( select count(*) from asset_usages y
      where x.asset_id = y.asset_id 
        and y.viewed_at < x.viewed_at
    ) as rn,
    x.* 
  from asset_usages x
) alias
) alias1;
```

Comment: This froze out my mysql server (i killed it after 30 minutes).  I neglected to mention i have 800,000 + records in the table, i think this is recursing too much for the server to handle.

Answer (score 0):

This SELECT statement will give you the right data. You might need to do the update in chunks, though.

You can drop the ORDER BY clause for the UPDATE statement. As written, the derived data doesn't depend on the order of rows in the outer SELECT statement.

```
select asset_id, viewer_id, viewer_type, viewed_at, 
       prev_viewed_at, timestampdiff(second, prev_viewed_at, viewed_at) elapsed_sec
from (select asset_id, viewer_id, viewer_type, viewed_at,
            (select max(t2.viewed_at) 
             from Table1 t2
             where t2.viewed_at < Table1.viewed_at
               and t2.asset_id = Table1.asset_id
               and t2.viewer_id = Table1.viewer_id
            ) prev_viewed_at
      from Table1
      )t3
order by asset_id, viewer_id, viewed_at;
```